# i want to export table content from word to excel with some filtering of particular row using VBscript

Tags: vba, vbscript

i have written this code but contain is not pasting continuously after filtering. Please help!
e.g.
 word is containing some rows in 5th column value is either "y" or "n". i want to copy only those rows which containing "y" in their 5th column. my code is here.

```
 Function FnPrint()

  Dim objWord

  Dim objDoc

  Dim wdFileName As Variant
Dim TableNo As Integer 'table number in Word
Dim iRow As Long 'row index in Excel
Dim iCol As Integer 'column index in Excel

  Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

  Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("D:\doc1.docx")

  objWord.Visible = False

  With objDoc
TableNo = objDoc.tables.Count


   If TableNo = 0 Then
            MsgBox "This document contains no tables", _
            vbExclamation, "Import Word Table"
        ElseIf TableNo > 1 Then
            TableNo = InputBox("This Word document contains " & TableNo & " tables." & vbCrLf & _
            "Enter table number of table to import", "Import Word Table", "1")
        End If
        With .tables(TableNo)
            'copy cell contents from Word table cells to Excel cells
            For iRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
                'determine if the text of the 5th column contains the word "y"
              If .cell(iRow, 5).Range.Text Like "*y*" Then
                    'find the last empty row in the current worksheet
                    'nextRow = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                    For iCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
'ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(nextRow, iCol) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(iRow, iCol).Range.Text)
  Cells(iRow, iCol) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(iRow, iCol).Range.Text)
                    Next iCol
                End If
            Next iRow
        End With
    End With
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
End Function
```

[this is the word table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qqtP.jpg)

[this is what my code pasting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHKaU.jpg)

I don't want that empty row in between.please help.

Comment: you are using iRow to address the worksheet. it increments for all rows in word document table. ... use a separate index variable that you increment only when you find a matching row